# How do I search server names I'm subscribed to on Discord.com

Tags: discord

When you're subscribed to a lot of servers on discord it's hard to find the server you wish to jump to. How do I search my list of subscribed servers?

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the home button in the top left corner.
2. Click the "Find or start a conversation" button.
3. A popup will display allowing you to search your list of subscribed servers.

[image]